# Numpy: convert a grid/array to a dictionary using a anther numpy array as label

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert a numpy array to a dictionary. The keys for the indices are stored in another array (in the order). The rows 1,2,3,4 represents `a,b,c,d` respectively. and so the columns too.

The values of the grid repesents the nearness of the letter to one another.

```
label = np.array(['a','b','c','d'])

grid_Arr = np.array([[1. , 0.3, 0.5, 0.6],
       [0.3, 1. , 0.4, 0.1],
       [0.5, 0.4, 1. , 0.2],
       [0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 1. ]])
```

So we can see the diagonal elements are 1 as it compares the same letter with each other.

I'm trying to convert this to a dict of the form:

```
[{'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'a', 'score': 1},
{'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'b', 'score': 0.3},
{'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'c', 'score': 0.5},
{'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 0.6},
{'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'b', 'score': 1},
{'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'b', 'score': 0.3},
{'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'c', 'score': 0.5},
{'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 0.6},
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems inconsistent. You list "b -> b" twice with different values, and have "b -> c" listed with a value of 0.5, which looks more like "a -> c", and so on...

But perhaps something like this could get you on the right track:

```py
y, x = np.triu_indices_from(grid_Arr)

[
    {
        "word1": w1,
        "word2": w2, 
        "score": s,
    } for w1,w2,s in zip(
        label[y], 
        label[x], 
        grid_Arr[y,x],
    )
]
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'a', 'score': 1.0},
 {'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'b', 'score': 0.3},
 {'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'c', 'score': 0.5},
 {'word1': 'a', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 0.6},
 {'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'b', 'score': 1.0},
 {'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'c', 'score': 0.4},
 {'word1': 'b', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 0.1},
 {'word1': 'c', 'word2': 'c', 'score': 1.0},
 {'word1': 'c', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 0.2},
 {'word1': 'd', 'word2': 'd', 'score': 1.0}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the question now